# How to change the CassandraHost for Helenos-GUI?

Tags: cassandra, helenus

Helenos tries to connect to localhost:9160 by default.

For some reasons, localhost doesn't work for me.

So I get this error message in catalina.out:

ERROR HConnectionManager - Could not start connection pool for host localhost(127.0.0.1):9160

It it possible to change the host and/or port?

I haven't found any config options for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's some workaround for this issue. You may find a H2 database in your home dir (helenos.h2.db file). Connect and run following queries...

```
DELETE FROM CLUSTERCONFIG;
INSERT INTO CLUSTERCONFIG VALUES('default', 'yourhostname:9160', 'clustername', true);
```

and restart.